# How do you make notations visible outside of a module signature in Coq?

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I've defined a module signature in Coq that defines several notations. When I try to use these notations outside of the signature however, Coq fails. A simplified version of my code is given below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Module Type Field_Axioms.

  Delimit Scope Field_scope with F.
  Open Scope Field_scope.

  Parameter Element : Set.

  Parameter addition : Element -> Element -> Element.

  Infix " + " := addition : Field_scope. (* ASSIGNS THE "+" OPERATOR TO SCOPE. *)

End Field_Axioms

Module Type Ordered_Field_Axioms.

  Declare Module Field : Field_Axioms.

  Print Scope Field_scope. (* SHOWS THAT THE SCOPE IS EMPTY. *)

End Ordered_Field_Axioms.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace:

```
Declare Module Field : Field_Axioms.
```

with:

```
Declare Module Import Field : Field_Axioms.
```